# Advice on persisting data via URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

When a user logs into my application they are presented with a list of specific items they can manage. Once an item is selected, I want to persist the item's unique ID via the URL instead of using sessions.

I have created a custom ActionFilterAttribute that checks the query string for that ID and then assigns a ViewBag property that can be used by the calling controller and view.

I then manually create my form/input tags explicitly setting the ID to the Viewbag property for routevalues. (i.e. ActionLink and BeginForm)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Item Detail", "Index", "ItemManagement", new { @itemId = ViewBag.ItemId}, null)
```

Is this the right way to go about it? Is there a easier way to include the Viewbag property on all ActionLinks and BeginForm tags instead of manually doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the reason for doing it this way instead of using a custom HTTP header, or a cookie?

Comment: You will need to create your own helper method; seeing as how you've already created your own attribute it doesn't sound like that would be very difficult for you.